# Multi criteria case statement in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, case

I am working on a calculated column that will return an "X" if specific criteria are met. The criteria are based pm three columns. The table actually has several columns.

```
COLUMN1     COLUMN2     COLUMN3     DATE
1234          100         300       1/1/2002
2245          100         500       2/3/2002   
1234          400         400       4/5/2007
2256          100         500       7/5/2010
1234
```

The calcucated column will return and x if COLUMN1 has a value of 1234 OR IF COLUMN2 has 2 consecutive values < 200 within a 2 year period or COLUMN3 has 2 consecutive values > 300 within a 2 year period

According to this criteria row 1,3, and 5 will return an X due to the number 1234.
According to Column 2 row 1 will return an X due to the fact that there was a value less then 200 twice in a row within a 2 year period..

Any help would be greatly appreciated....

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be quite slow on larger volumes of data due to the self join, but should provide you with the data you are looking for...

```
CREATE TABLE #data
(column1 INT
,column2 INT
,column3 INT
,column4 DATETIME)
INSERT INTO #data 
SELECT 1234         , 100    ,     300     ,'1/1/2002' UNION ALL
SELECT 2245        ,  100    ,     500     ,'2/3/2002'  UNION ALL
SELECT  1234      ,    400   ,      400     ,' 4/5/2007' UNION ALL
SELECT 2256      ,    100    ,     500      ,'7/5/2010' UNION ALL
SELECT 1234     , NULL,NULL,NULL

;with CTE AS
(
SELECT * 
,row_number() OVER (ORDER BY CASE WHEN column4 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END DESC) as row
FROM #data
)
SELECT DISTINCT 
c1.row
,c1.column1
,c1.column2
,c1.column3
,c1.column4
,CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(YY,c1.column4,c2.column4) < 2 AND c1.column2 < 200 AND c2.column2 < 200 THEN 'X'
        WHEN c1.column1 = 1234 THEN 'X'
        WHEN DATEDIFF(YY,c1.column4,c2.column4) < 2 AND c1.column3 > 300 AND c2.column3 > 300 THEN 'X' 
        END AS column5
FROM CTE c1
LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE c2
ON c1.row + 1 = c2.row 
ORDER BY c1.row ASC
```

Comment: Great, i will give this a try...I will post my findings..Thank you very much